# Symfony autoloader component

Tags: php, symfony, twig, autoloader

I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem'

```
<?php

require_once "library/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php";

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace("Symfony\Component", "library/Symfony/Component");
$loader->registerPrefix("Twig_", "library/Twig");
$loader->register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '',
));

?>
```

The Twig folder is in library folder. Have I missunderstood on how to use the component?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\bootstrap.php on line 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you sure your path is correct?
2. Try to use `__DIR__ . '/library'`
3. Try to use [`DebugUniversalClassLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/blob/master/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php) to pin down the problem - you can catch a `RuntimeException` and see which file it actually tries to load.

**EDIT**:

Correct solution: If you try to load PEAR-style classes with prefix `Twig_` from `'/library/Twig'`, you should point it to `'/library'`, because `Twig_` prefix itself will be used as a directory name inside `/library`

Comment: The path is "ROOT"-folder "library" "Twig", the Symfony is placed in "library" folder as well, so yes the path must be correct.

Comment: Try to use `$loader->registerPrefix("Twig_", __DIR__ . "/library");` instead. You can how it choses the file here: https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/blob/master/UniversalClassLoader.php#L297